# unity3d, animation stuck at 1st frame

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

i have a menu scene and scene A, scene B. when i go to scene A, a 3D object will play some animation, and i have some button to click and make it animation also, but from menu if i go to scene B, i come back to menu then i go scene A, all the animation in scene A will not working, "animation.isPlaying" is showing true. if i disable the starting animation, and click those animate button, "animation.isPlaying" turn from false to true also. but it just wont move, just like stuck at 1st frame, any help will be appreciate...

Comment: This question would appear to be of more value to the general community if it was grammatically structured properly and provided clearly detailed specifics of the problem and symptoms experienced.

Answer (score 2):

problem fix, in case you want to know why, is because i stop the "time" at another scene, and i didn't expect that it will still remain even when the scene was killed.